# xparse - order of token-type args

Tags: macros, xparse

I am curious if there is a technical reason that the token-type args of xparse must follow the correct order?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{s t+}{---
\IfBooleanT{#1}{star }
\IfBooleanT{#2}{plus }---\par}
\begin{document}
\foo \foo* \foo+ \foo*+ \foo+*
%                        swapping order doesn't work
\end{document}
```

Comment: it would be more work to allow any order (and not really any clearer, and would make the behaviour of `{ss}` rather harder to define.

Comment: most people think of a command like `\section*` as a command with name `section*` (rather than a command with a boolean marker following)  so it would be odd to allow `\section + *` to be a variant of `\section*`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my thought, for example, was that `+` wouldn't be a modifier for `\section*`, but just another modififer for `section`. For example, `*` disables number and ToC entry, but `+` could change the style of the section text, for exampke. How `**` would be handled IMO is one `*` is True False and two `**` is True True, Just wanted to throw this out there, hopefully it brings some consideration for `xparse`--an incredibly useful package btw, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking for an optional `*` which can be followed by an optional `+`. The combination `+*` has not been envisaged in the definition, so with

```
\foo+*
```

the command `\IfBooleanT{#1}` returns false (hence nothing).

Do you want to allow any combination? Then you have to work harder.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{}
 {
  \peek_regex_replace_once:nn
   {% at most two characters among * and +
    (\*|\+){0,2}
   }
   {% replace with
    \c{veget_foo:n}\{\0\}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \veget_foo:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {}{nothing}
    {*}{star}
    {+}{plus}
    {*+}{star~and~plus}
    {+*}{star~and~plus}
    {**}{star*}
    {++}{plus+}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foo

\foo+

\foo*

\foo+*

\foo*+

\foo++

\foo**

\foo*+*

\foo++*

\end{document}
```

[image]